# Can't install additional VM with virt-install

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, virt-install

Installing an additional VM with the virt-install command results in the following error:

```
ERROR    internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2019-02-20T08:21:45.534416Z qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=/home/chris/VM/ubuntu-16.04.iso,format=raw,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,readonly=on: Could not open '/home/chris/VM/ubuntu-16.04.iso': Permission denied
```

This is my virt-install command:

```
sudo virt-install \
-n VPNserver \
--description "VPN server" \
--os-type=Linux \
--os-variant=ubuntu16.04 \
--ram=1096 \
--vcpus=1 \
--disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/vpnserver.img,bus=virtio,size=10 \
--network bridge:br2 \
--graphics none \
--location /home/chris/VM/ubuntu-16.04.iso \
--extra-args console=ttyS0 \
--autostart
```

File permissions in /chris/home/VM/:

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 chris        chris        93 Jan  3 14:15 Fileserver.README
-rwx------ 1 chris        chris       334 Nov 21 09:20 installFileserver
-rwx------ 1 chris        chris       332 Feb 20 08:21 installVPNServer
-rwx------ 1 chris        chris       331 Nov 21 09:20 installWebserver
-rw-rw-rw- 1 chris        chris       795 Jan 24 13:10 README.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 libvirt-qemu kvm   912261120 Jul 31  2018 ubuntu-16.04.iso`

Similar question:

[virt-install cannot use ISO file as location](https://serverfault.com/questions/833131/virt-install-cannot-use-iso-file-as-location)

**What I've tried...**

1) "chown" the iso file to user 'chris'

2) Moved the file to the /tmp directory

3) Sudo -s and executed script.

4) Redownload the iso image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible $HOME permissions are too strict. It is not sufficient for the ISO to be readable - each parent directory needs to have 'x' permission too.

ApArmor or SELinux could be denying access to files under $HOME and/or /tmp

Since you're using the privileged libvirtd the recommended approach is to simply keep the ISO images under /var/lib/libvirt/images/ too, alongside the disks.

Comment: Thank you, the permissions were wrong for the 'VM' folder.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar case where `virt-install` failed with:

```
Starting install...
Retrieving file vmlinuz...                                                                                                                                            | 9.4 MB  00:00:00
Retrieving file initrd.img...                                                                                                                                         |  72 MB  00:00:00
ERROR    internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start mymachine.local
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

After goofing around, I noticed the OOM shooting the created machine, found after looking at machine state with `dmesg`.

Since I configured hugepages to take almost all my hypervisor memory so machines get fast reserved space, I needed to add `--memorybacking hugepages=yes` to my `virt-install` command.

Comment: This is helpful, but not relevant to the problem described above. You should instead [ask and answer your own question](/help/self-answer) so that others with the _same_ issue can find it.

Answer (score 0):

virt-install runs under qemu user. You will find on ISO file user and group would have changed to qemu. This user would not have permissions to see /home/chris and sub-folders. You should copy iso to a folder like /tmp and that should take care of the issue.